# How to install kibana time plugin?

Tags: plugins, kibana

I am trying to install the kibana time plugin from github https://github.com/nreese/kibana-time-plugin.
I have kibana 4.6.2 running properly and was able to install sense without any problem.
But for time plugin the error which i'm getting is " no valid url specified ".Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems like the [url](https://github.com/nreese/kibana-time-plugin/archive/4.x.zip) is working fine. Could you show the way you've tried to install the plugin?

Comment: I've tried this command : kibana plugin -i kibana-time-plugin -u https://github.com/nreese/kibana-time-plugin/archive/4.x.zip   . I even tried by downloading the zip file from github and using the command --install file://path  , but still no luck.

Comment: according to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/4.2/kibana-plugins.html#_installing_plugins_from_an_arbitrary_url), your command looks fine. Might be a version compatibility issue.

Comment: I am using kibana-4.6.2 ...so this shouldnt be a version issue. If it's a proxy issue then how do i solve it?

Comment: You mean the proxy of kibana ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

./bin/kibana plugin -i kibana-time-plugin -u https://github.com/nreese/kibana-time-plugin/archive/4.x.zip